# Airflow KubernetesPodOperator Losing Connection to Worker Pod

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod

Experiencing an odd issue with KubernetesPodOperator on Airflow 1.1.14.

Essentially for some jobs Airflow is losing contact with the pod it creates.

`[2021-02-10 07:30:13,657] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))`

When I check logs in kubernetes with `kubectl logs` I can see that the job carried on past the connection broken error.

The connection broken error seems to happen exactly 1 hour after the last logs that Airflow pulls from the pod (we do have a 1 hour config on connections), but the pod keeps running happily in the background.

I've seen this behaviour repeatedly, and it tends to happen with longer running jobs with a gap in the log output, but I have no other leads. Happy to update the question if certain specifics are misssing.

Comment: Have you tried to set operators  `get_logs`  parameter to  `False` -  default value is  `True` ? Take a look:  [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3534](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3534)  [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5571](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5571)

Comment: Ooh, looks very plausible, will try!

Comment: Was my comment useful ? Did you manage to solve problem using tips from it?

Comment: Hi @Malgorzata I think this solves it, I've only tried on dev which doesn't unfortunately have the high load jobs, but following the breadcrumb trail from that issue, this seems right. It looks like airflow could solve it by allowing a param or upping the retries here - https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b23fc137812f5eabf7834e07e032915e2a504c17/airflow/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py#L198

Comment: Ok, so I will paste it as an answer to be more visible for community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in comments section I think you can try to set operators  `get_logs`  parameter to  `False`  - default value is  `True` .

Take a look:  [airflow-connection-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176707/airflow-worker-connection-broken-incompleteread0-bytes-read),  [airflow-connection-issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3534) .

Comment: Thanks I raised -https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14259 as I think they could make much better changing a 3 to a 5